# can anyone explain what is written inside parenthesis means?

Tags: c

```
#define DATASIZE (10<<20)
```

I can not understand what is written inside parenthesis  mean ,i.e 10<<20 . can anyone explain to me ?

Comment: [Bitwise shifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23.2C_Python)

Answer (score 1):

This is bitwise left shift.
Refer [this](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-bitwise-left-shift-operator/).

And try to search things first :)